# Поиск предыдущего значения в массиве по условию

Tags: php

Приветствую!

Прошу помочь решить задачу.
Есть массив:

```
Array  (
[2015] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Высшая] => Array
                    (
                        [tournament points] => 1030
                        [tournament place] => 99
                        [name] => Антон Савицкий
                        [playerid] => 13
                        [tour number] => 1
                        [all players in this league and season] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 3900
                                        [playerid] => 11
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 1030
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 200
                                        [playerid] => 12
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 100
                                        [playerid] => 14
                                    )

                                [11] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 3900
                                        [playerid] => 11
                                    )

                                [13] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 1030
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [12] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 200
                                        [playerid] => 12
                                    )

                                [14] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 100
                                        [playerid] => 14
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [Первая] => Array
                    (
                        [tournament points] => 50
                        [tournament place] => 1
                        [name] => Антон Савицкий
                        [playerid] => 13
                        [tour number] => 1
                        [all players in this league and season] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [13] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Высшая] => Array
                    (
                        [tournament points] => 2230
                        [tournament place] => 1
                        [name] => Антон Савицкий
                        [playerid] => 13
                        [tour number] => 2
                        [all players in this league and season] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 2230
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [13] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 2230
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [Первая] => Array
                    (
                        [tournament points] => 8230
                        [tournament place] => 1
                        [name] => Антон Савицкий
                        [playerid] => 13
                        [tour number] => 5
                        [all players in this league and season] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50500
                                        [playerid] => 14
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50000
                                        [playerid] => 12
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 8230
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [14] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50500
                                        [playerid] => 14
                                    )

                                [12] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50000
                                        [playerid] => 12
                                    )

                                [13] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 8230
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [Высшая] => Array
                    (
                        [tournament points] => 280
                        [tournament place] => 1
                        [name] => Антон Савицкий
                        [playerid] => 13
                        [tour number] => 6
                        [all players in this league and season] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 280
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [13] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 280
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [Первая] => Array
                    (
                        [tournament points] => 50230
                        [tournament place] => 1
                        [name] => Антон Савицкий
                        [playerid] => 13
                        [tour number] => 6
                        [all players in this league and season] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50230
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 2000
                                        [playerid] => 12
                                    )

                                [13] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 50230
                                        [playerid] => 13
                                    )

                                [12] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total] => 2000
                                        [playerid] => 12
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Я создаю рейтинг игроков. 
2015, это сезон, далее идет номер турнира и тип лиги.
Для каждого игрока нужно получить номер места, который он занял в прошлом турнире конкретной лиги, значение ["tournament place"].

Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать?

Вот мой код:

```
 $prev_object = FALSE;
                        $next_object = FALSE;
                        $cur_object = FALSE;
                        $allow_next = FALSE;
                        $skip_iter = FALSE;
                        $total_from_prev_tournaments = array();
                        foreach ($season as $product_scroll_item_key => $product_scroll_item) {
                            foreach ($product_scroll_item as $league_key_scroll => $league_scroll) {
                                $categoryItems[$product_scroll_item_key][] = $product_scroll_item_key;

                                if ($product_scroll_item_key == $tournumber_key && $league_key == $league_key_scroll) {

                                    $allow_next = TRUE;
                                    $skip_iter = TRUE;
                                    if (!$cur_object) {
                                        $prev_object = FALSE;
                                        echo '0';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $prev_object = $cur_object;
                                        echo $league_key_scroll;
                                        echo $prev_object . '  ' . $product_scroll_item_key . "  " . $tournumber_key . "  " . $league_key . "  " . $league_key_scroll . " конец ";

                                        if ($prev_object > 0) {
                                            if ($this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$prev_object][$league_key_scroll]['total with prev'] > 0) {
                                                //echo "2";
                                                $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['prev'] = $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$prev_object][$league_key_scroll]['tournament points'];
                                                $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['total with prev'] = $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['tournament points'] + $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$prev_object][$league_key_scroll]['total with prev'];
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                if ($this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$prev_object][$league_key_scroll]['tournament points'] > 0) {
                                                    $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['prev'] = $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$prev_object][$league_key_scroll]['tournament points'];
                                                    $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['total with prev'] = $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['tournament points'] + $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['prev'];
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {

                                        }
                                        if ($this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['total with prev'] > 0) {
                                            echo $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['total with prev'] - $this->rates_array_sort[$season_key][$product_scroll_item_key][$league_key_scroll]['tournament points'];
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo '0';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($allow_next && !$skip_iter) {
                                    $next_object = $product_scroll_item_key;
                                    $allow_next = FALSE;
                                }
                                $cur_object = $product_scroll_item_key;
                                $skip_iter = FALSE;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: что такое "прошлый турнир"?

Comment: У каждого турнира есть номер, в данном примере 1,2,5,6. Номер турнира идет после года "2015". Прошлый турнир, это когда берется текущее значение номера турнира и ищется в массиве прошлый номер турнира в котором принимал участие данный игрок.

Comment: А откуда этот массив? Мне кажется, структура переусложнена, а вы пришли к этому массиву, скорее всего, неверным путем, так как эффективно что-либо сделать на подобной структуре очень проблематично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу следующим образом. 
Пришлось сделать отдельный массив с номерами турниров:

```
Array
(
[2015] => Array
    (
        [Высшая] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 4
            )

        [Первая] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5
                [1] => 6
            )

    )
)
```

Дальше просто прошел по массиву циклом и получил предыдущий ключ:

```
$totalnumbers = 0;
                            $prev_object = FALSE;
                            $next_object = FALSE;
                            foreach ($tour_numbers as $season_tour_numbers_key => $season_tour_numbers_value) {
                                foreach ($season_tour_numbers_value as $league_tour_numbers_key => $league_tour_numbers_value) {
                                    foreach ($league_tour_numbers_value as $tour_numbers_key => $tour_numbers_value) {
                                        if ($tournumber_key > $tour_numbers_value && $league_tour_numbers_key == $league_key) {
                                            $totalnumbers += $this->rates_array_sort[$season_tour_numbers_key][$tour_numbers_value][$league_tour_numbers_key]['tournament points'];
                                        }
                                        if ($tournumber_key == $tour_numbers_value && $league_tour_numbers_key == $league_key) {
                                            if (isset($tour_numbers[$season_tour_numbers_key][$league_tour_numbers_key][$tour_numbers_key - 1])) {
                                                $prev_object = $tour_numbers[$season_tour_numbers_key][$league_tour_numbers_key][$tour_numbers_key - 1];
                                            }
                                            if (isset($tour_numbers[$season_tour_numbers_key][$league_tour_numbers_key][$tour_numbers_key + 1])) {
                                                $next_object = $tour_numbers[$season_tour_numbers_key][$league_tour_numbers_key][$tour_numbers_key + 1];
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```